# Center align form with image in the end

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
center {
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid rgb(161, 161, 161);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: rgb(173, 173, 173)" style="width: 100">
  <h1 class="center">Sign up for our newsletter! </h1>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</div>
```

Comment: So... what's your problem ? what are you actually trying to achieve

Comment: what is the statement of the problem ?

Comment: i want to make the photo i have uploaded into my code.

Comment: sorry if my question is in bad shape..but this is the first time i use stackoverhlow and of course the first time i make a question...i want to create a template..and this is a piece of the template and i want it under another div as a form

Comment: the title talks about an image, but your question doesn't mention it... It doesn't even have text actually :/ 
Where's the code for the form you are trying to make? is the img in it or under it in the same parent div?

Comment: also you should use margin or padding and not a bunch of <br> to align stuff

Comment: i added the code in the formula but it disappeared.I am trying to edit it ..yes i know that i have to use padding and margin ..project is not finished yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css to center your block vertically

```
display:flex;
align-content:middle;
justify-content:center;
```

Comment: what should i use as name of this style?

Comment: you create a new class